# Can i put .htaccess file in subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess

i am using sub folders to show demo websites. So is it possible to put .htaccess file separately in each of folder.

Comment: In future, please try to ask more specific questions as what you have tried and what exact error you were getting

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely you can do that. Every folder will follow the rules mentioned in the individual `.htaccess` file

Comment: Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html